# Vb.net Passing values to constructor of Type T

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have this code to get the default constructor:

```
Public Function f(ByVal t As System.Type) As Object
    Return t.GetConstructor(New System.Type() {}).Invoke(New Object() {})
End Function
```

I need to pass values to the Constructor as

```
Public Function f(ByVal t As System.Type) As Object
    Return t.GetConstructor(New System.Type() {someInteger,someString,etc.etc}).Invoke(New Object() {}) 
End Function
```

Also I have 3 classes of Type `T`, with all having different parametric constructor. It's important for me to have it generic as the Classes of type `T` might increase in future with less or more parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

However, you are putting the values in the `Type()`. You need to specify the types of the constructor, so it knows which constructor you want to actually resolve, then pass the actual values you wish in `Invoke`:

```
Public Function f(ByVal t As System.Type) As Object
    Return t.GetConstructor(New System.Type() {GetType(Integer),GetType(String)}).Invoke(New Object() {someInteger, someString}) 
End Function
```